# How to swap Capslock and Ctrl without having capslock mode activated unintentionally?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, ctrl, capslock

I have a simple AutoHotKey script:

```
Capslock::Ctrl
#Capslock::Capslock
```

The point is, occasionally the capslock mode is activated even though I only want it to function as Ctrl, and I can't make it stop. The only way to do that is suspense the script, fix it, then reactivate it.

How can I make it works as intended?

---

## Key history

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
----------------------------------------------
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.06    CapsLock        
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.03    Control         
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.00    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   d   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   d   0.00    Control         
14  03A h   u   0.03    CapsLock        
11  01D i   u   0.00    Control
```

Comment: I tried it and I didn't get capslock to activate once except when pressing windowskey plus capslock as expected. But I did get warning when holding capslock for a couple of seconds about large number of hotkeys received in short period and to check #MaxHotkeysPerInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [the answer of johnlee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022533/3416774), it can be because

> the script itself is too busy doing something else or the OS is not giving enough time slices to the script due to other tasks hogging the CPU

so there is nothing else I can do. So my solution is

## `#Space::Capslock`

Using `Capslock::Ctrl` is better than `Capslock::SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl Down}` because it doesn't activate <kbd>Shift + Ctrl</kbd> when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed first.

Answer (score 1):

One noticeable problem with your code is that `Ctrl` is a modifier key while `Capslock` is not, which will produce unexpected results, including what Roman described.

Try this instead:

```
Capslock::SendInput {Ctrl Down}
Capslock Up::SendInput {Ctrl Up}
#Capslock::Capslock
```

Comment: Why does pressing `Shift + Caps` (`Shift` first) activate the capslock mode?

Answer (score 1):

To answer:

> Why does pressing `Shift + Caps` (`Shift` first) activate the capslock mode?

Because `+Capslock` is technically another hotkey you might want to assign another task to by adding another entry `+Capslock::` and is therefore not captured by `Capslock::` by default.

To capture all combinations without adding separate entries for each combination, try:

```
*Capslock::SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl Down}
*Capslock Up::SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl Up}
```

But then, this *might* interfere with the `#Capslock::` entry depending on the context.

So, it's safe to specify all possible combos though it'd look a bit too complex and even ugly.

**Edit:**

Regarding the key history you added,

1. Do you see 3 `CapsLock` entries followed by only 2 `Control` ones in the middle? I guess that's where the script somehow 'missed' the key press event, which happens when the script itself is too busy doing something else or the OS is not giving enough time slices to the script due to other tasks hogging the CPU.
2. I've mapped an infrequently used key to modify and map <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd>, and sometimes the same thing happens, too. Like if I press and hold a combination for a while to, say, go up 100+ lines, it leaves an unexpected `i` in the middle. Not always, but *sometimes*.
3. Nonetheless, using `Process Priority,, A` at the top of the script *does* help, making the glitch happen much less often.

Comment: this happens again. Do you know why is that?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. You could look into it by double-clicking the tray icon and pressing ctrl+H to see key history. If all else fails, add an entry `+Capslock::`.

Comment: so the only way to avoid the glitch is to make the script more prioritized? Why don't we make it top priority?

Comment: In general, you do *not* want to set the priority of any user thread to anything above `AboveNormal`, which might undermine system stability. You could experiment with `High`, though I would not.

Comment: The mysterious thing is that this key sequence happens at the first place. I hardly use Capslock, so the history should have had only Controls

Comment: It's *not* so mysterious if you learn more about it. Events could certainly be missed in certain situations. Alternatively, you might want to consider using SharpKeys to permanently map `CapsLock` to `Control`.